# Class: "amsart", Package "newtxtext", "theoremfont" option. No bold text in Theorem body

Tags: amsart

Using the class `amsart`, with

```
\usepackage[theoremfont]{newtxtext}
```

the command `\textbf` has no effect in the the body of a theorem.

I am using TeXlive 2020, on MacOS.

Any solutions, explanations? Changing the order in the preamble doesn't solve the problem.

`newpxtext` doesn't have this problem. MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[theoremfont]{newtxtext}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    Normal text. \textbf{Bold text.}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `theoremfont` option changes the font used in the `plain` theorem style (as defined by `amsthm`) to a special version of the italic font that has upright digits, parentheses and punctuation.

The (devious) trick it uses is to assign this special font to the slanted shape and in the font definition file `t1ntxtlf.fd` we find

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ntxtlf}{m}{sl}{<-> \ntx@scaled ntx-Italic-tlf-th-t1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ntxtlf}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * ntxtlf/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ntxtlf}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * ntxtlf/m/sl}{}
```

so there is no bold version for this font.

Workaround: use `\textbf{\textit{Bold font.}}`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[theoremfont]{newtxtext}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Normal text. \textbf{\textit{Bold text.}}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or simply don't use boldface in theorem statements, which is much better.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and expert answer!  

I don't usually use boldface in theorem statements.  

I was correcting someonelse's TeX file, and decided to replace his fonts with newtx.  

He was using $\mathbf{x}$ which gives an upright bold "x" in the theorem text.  

newtxtext "destroyed" this effect!  

Anyway: the author of newtx should warn about this, in his (very long) documentation.

Comment: @rlsx As far as I can see, `$\mathbf{x}$` works as expected. Not `\textbf`, though, as you discovered.

Comment: Another problem with "newtxtext" : it won't keep footnote numbers straight in an italic context (whether "theorem" or inside \emph{...} )

Comment: `$\mathbf{x}$` works indeed as expected. I was mistaken. What actually happens: if you load package `biolinum` **after** `newtxtext` but **before** `newtxtmath`, it kills the boldface in `$\mathbf{x}$`, apparenly everywhere. Independently of the option `theoremfont`.